# Display webpage before loading images

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, image

I have a page with lots of large images on it, meaning that the loading time is quite long.

I would like to display the page as it is without any images first, and then have the images load one by one. This would mean that users could begin using the page (the images are not crucial for this) before the browser has loaded everything.

How can I do this? At the moment, the page only gets displayed once all the images have been loaded.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please do some proper research before posting a question. There are literally hundreds, of not even thousands of examples, tutorials and libraries that can help you with this if you do some google searches. The question is also too unspecific and broad for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a transparent pixel in the source and attach a special class:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkqAcAAIUAgUW0RjgAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" data-src="/path/to/real-image.jpg" class="lazy" />
```

Then at the end of your body add this script to swap the data-src to src, so the browser loads the image.

```
<script>
(function loadImages() {
    var imgDefer = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for (var i = 0; i < imgDefer.length; i++) {
        if (imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src') && imgDefer[i].classList.contains('lazy')) {
            imgDefer[i].setAttribute('src', imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src'));
        }
    }
}());
</script>
```

Comment: Please don't answer clearly off-topic questions. The OP shows zero attempts of solving the issue on their own, nor does it seem like they've even done much research. Doing so will just make people to keep asking off-topic questions, turning SO into a free coding service.